How get parent's value from DataFetchingEnvironment?
I have implemented service with GraphQL on spring-boot-starter-graphql
It is simple schema, where field c depends on id B
type A {
  id: Int!
  b: [B]
}

type B {
  id: Int!
  с: C
}

type C {
  с: C //depends on id type B
}

Controller and DataLoader
@QueryMapping
public A getA(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
    A a = repo.getA();
    int index = 0;
    for (B b : a.getB()) {
        environment.getGraphQlContext().put(index, b.getId());
        index++;
    }
    return A;
}

@SchemaMapping(field = "c", typeName = "C")
public C getC(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
    Integer currentIndex = environment.getExecutionStepInfo().getParent().getParent().getPath().getSegmentIndex();
    C c = repo2.getC(environment.getGraphQlContext().get(currentIndex));
    return c;
}

I put id of Type B to GraphQlContext in QueryMapping. Example: (index, id) -> (0,123) (1,247)
In SchemaMapping I have only Type C and I can not get Type B, so I use GraphQlContext.
Can I get parent's (Type B) values from DataFetchingEnvironment without using GraphQlContext?
I use GraphQlContext, but not sure this is best solution
